# What type of data is returned from pandas_datareader.get_data_yahoo function?

Tags: python, data-structures, pandas-datareader

What type of data is returned from pandas_datareader.get_data_yahoo function? Is it Array, List, Dictionary or Object? How can i figure it out?

This is sample code for downloading data:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('EURUSD=X')
```

Comment: `type(df)` might help

Answer (score 1):

It's a pandas' dataframe and has many attributes.

You can see that it is a dataframe with the following code:

```
isinstance(pdr.get_data_yahoo('EURUSD=X'), pd.DataFrame)
```

And you can see the attributes with the following code:

```
dir(pdr.get_data_yahoo('EURUSD=X'))
```